# 'Property 'Name' is ReadOnly.' crystal report [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I tried to change Font properties of the Field and Text objects in a Crystal report By VB.NET. But I have Error
**'Property 'Name' is ReadOnly.' crystal report** or **'Property 'Size' is ReadOnly.' crystal report**

My code :

```
With CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource.Section3

    '---Left
    .ReportObjects("expiry1").Left = 100
    .ReportObjects("expiry2").Left = 500

    '---Top
    .ReportObjects("expiry1").Top = 100
    .ReportObjects("expiry2").Top = 100

    '---Font        
    .ReportObjects("expiry1").Font.Name = "Arial"
    .ReportObjects("expiry1").Font.Size = 16

End With
```

What a mistake? and How can I change Font properties of the Field and Text objects in a Crystal report? I want font name Arial size 16 and bold.
Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Do you have a way to edit the report in the Report Designer?  This could be done with Crystal Report Designer software or a Crystal Report plug-in for Visual Studio typically.

Comment: @R.McMillan Yes I have but I have a reason to use the code to edit Font properties only. So I used this method.

Answer (score 1):

The properties of the [`Font`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.font)-Class are all `ReadOnly`.

To change the font you have to create a new `Font` with the required settings:

```
.ReportObjects("expiry1").Font = New Font("Arial", 16)
```